# Can not change background in view

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to change the background color of my view. I wrote some code and i can change color with animation, but first time my view is freezing before color changes. This is my code

```
private void changeBackgroundColorWithAnimation(int duration, final View view, int startColor, int endColor) {
    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(startColor, endColor);
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(final ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            view.setBackgroundColor((Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());

        }
    });

    anim.setDuration(duration);
    anim.start();
}
```

I call my function like this:

```
changeBackgroundColorWithAnimation(300, TransferFragmentNewVersion.rootLayout, 
    Color.parseColor("#E6000000"), Color.WHITE);
```

As I said the background color has changed, but first time View is freezing(only first time)l

How can I solve my problem? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you sending your view's initial color as a starting color?
You can replace `Color.parseColor("#E6000000")` with  `TransferFragmentNewVersion.rootLayout.getSolidColor()`.

Can you post more of your code?